# bash script to modify and extract information

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am creating a bash script to modify and summarize information with grep and sed. But it gets stuck.

```
    #!/bin/bash

# This script extracts some basic information
# from text files and prints it to screen.
#
# Usage: ./myscript.sh </path/to/text-file>


#Extract lines starting with ">@HWI" 

    ONLY=`grep -v ^\>@HWI`

#replaces A and G with R in lines

    ONLYR=`sed -e s/A/R/g -e s/G/R/g $ONLY`

    grep R $ONLYR | wc -l
```

Comment: You are kind of saying `grep pattern` but don't provide any file or string to match it against.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. What you are doing is manipulating text. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so instead of a shell script wrapping calls to grep and sed you should just be using one simple awk script. If you post come concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you do whatever it is you need to do the right way.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to write a shell script to do what you seem to be trying to do is:

```
awk '
    !/^>@HWI/ {
        gsub(/[AG]/,"R")
        if (/R/) {
            ++cnt
        }
    END { print cnt+0 }
' "$@"
```

Just put that in the file myscript.sh and execute it as you do today.

To be clear - the bulk of the above code is an awk script, the shell script part is the first and last lines where the shell just calls awk and passes it the input file names.

If you WANT to have intermediate variables then you can create/print them with:

```
awk '
    !/^>@HWI/ {
        only = $0
        onlyR = only
        gsub(/[AG]/,"R",onlyR)
        print "only:", only
        print "onlyR:", onlyR
        if (/R/) {
            ++cnt
        }
    END { print cnt+0 }
' "$@"
```

The above will work robustly, portably, and efficiently on all UNIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and as @fedorqui commented - you're not providing `grep` with a source of input, against which it will perform line matching.

Second, there are some problems in your script, which will result in unwanted behavior in the future, when you decide to manipulate some data:

- Store matching lines in an **array**, or a **file** from which you'll later read values. The variable `ONLY` is not the right data structure for the task.
- By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
  variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Here's a better version of your script, considering these points, but with an open question regarding what you were trying to do in the last line : `grep R $ONLYR | wc -l` :

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script extracts some basic information
# from text files and prints it to screen.
#
# Usage: ./myscript.sh </path/to/text-file>

input_file=$1

# Read lines not matching the provided regex, from $input_file
mapfile -t only < <(grep -v '^\>@HWI' "$input_file")

#replaces A and G with R in lines
for((i=0;i<${#only[@]};i++)); do
    only[i]="${only[i]//[AG]/R}"
done

# DEBUG
printf '%s\n' "Here are the lines, after relpace:"
printf '%s\n' "${only[@]}"

# I'm not sure what you were trying to do here. Am I gueesing right that you wanted
# to count the number of R's in ALL lines ?
# grep R $ONLYR | wc -l
```